# Track Kubernetes Deployments with kube_pod_container_info in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I am looking for a query to see when a container's image tag changes within a pod with Prometheus. I have tried a few different ways of doing and I think I am pretty close but the issue i can't seem to solve is how to compare the current record with the record from 5 minutes ago and only get results when the image changes but still include the pod and container data. I have this query so far
`kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} != on(image) kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m`

I get an error with this query because there are multiple containers running the same image. So ideally i would match the current records/past records on pod/container and then check to see if the images didn't match. here is an example of some of the data:
current data

```
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-1", image="test-image:v1"}
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2", image="test-image:v2"}
```

offset 5m data:

```
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-1", image="test-image:v1"}
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2", image="test-image:v1"}
```

From the data above would want to query to return `kube_pod_container_info{pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2", image="test-image:v2"}` as its container image was recently changed to the tag v2. Let me know if you need anymore clarification. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} == ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m 
  unless ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} ==
      kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m
```

Here we check if `kube_pod_container_info` matches all labels except `image` wtih itself 5 min ago, but not matches them all, then it means that `image` changed.

EDIT: Query to save all labels suggested by @JeffW

```
(kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} == ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m 
  unless ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} ==
      kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m )
* on(pod,cotainer) group_left(image) kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! It doesn't look like this works though because the results returned from the unless statement don't match the initial query without the image tag so all of the data still remains. In other words from the example it above it returns:`kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-1"}` and  `kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2"}`
instead of just
`kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2", image="test-image:v2"}`

Comment: @JeffW, sorry missed second ignoring. Corrected answer

Comment: Now it looks like we have the opposite problem of the unless canceling out all the records :)

Comment: @JeffW, very strange, shouldn't happen. Could you verify that for the evaluation time left part of unless return metric, and right not?

Comment: looks like there were some addition labels I needed to ignore! so this query produces `kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2"}`. Am I am able to join the results back with the current data to get `kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test",pod="test-pod", container="test-container-2", image="test-image:v2"}`?

Comment: was able to figure it out, with the following query if you want to update your answer and I can mark it correct: 
`(kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} == ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m 
  unless ignoring(image)
    kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} ==
      kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} offset 5m ) * on(pod,cotainer) group_left(image) kube_pod_container_info{namespace="test"} `

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JeffW, as I see my query worked, except that it dropped some labels. Cool trick with multiplication. Added to answer.